# Count based on values in column SQL Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as

```
Vote:

id | item_id | value
---------------------
1  |   1     | true
2  |   1     | false
3  |   1     | false
4  |   2     | true
5  |   2     | true
6  |   2     | false
7  |   2     | false
```

Where true is up and false is down.

Want a view to see the up/down vote for items as:

Required:

```
vw_item_vote:

item_id | up | down
---------------------
   1    | 1  | 2
   2    | 2  | 2
```

My current implementation:

```
CREATE vw_item_vote AS
    SELECT
        v.item_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN v.value = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS up,
        SUM(CASE WHEN v.value = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS down
    FROM
        vote v
    GROUP BY
        v.item_id,
        v.value;
```

Not giving the correct output.

Comment: Why are you grouping by value?

Comment: Yes, group by value is not required. Silly me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `v.value` from your `GROUP BY` clause, you don't need it.
Alternatively, using a `SUM` with an intention to get total count is somehow not really "clean code". If you're using **Postgres 9.4** or later, you can use `COUNT() WITH FILTER` instead.

See [Section 4.2.7. Aggregate Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-expressions.html)

```
WITH vote(id, item_id, value) AS (
    VALUES(1, 1, true),
    (1, 1, true),
    (2, 1, false),
    (3, 1, false),
    (4, 2, true),
    (5, 2, true),
    (6, 2, false),
    (7, 2, false),
    (8, 2, false),
    (9, 2, false),
    (10, 3, false)
)
SELECT item_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN value = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS up,
        SUM(CASE WHEN value = FALSE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS down,
        -- alternative options USING COUNT with FILTER with Postgres version after 9.4
        COUNT(value) FILTER (WHERE value IS TRUE) as up_alt,
        COUNT(value) FILTER (WHERE value IS FALSE) as down_alt
FROM vote
GROUP BY item_id;
```

| item_id | up | down | up_alt | down_alt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |